# How to pass jquery varibale value to html input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

how can pass the jquery var value to html input box

```
var m = $("#id_manufacturer").val();
var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td><input type='text' name='phoneManufacturer' value=m/></td></tr>
$("table tbody").append(markup);
```

this my code i want pass **var m** value to input box which i want to save into db via post method

i am working on django 
i have dynamic add row function to add rows and then save it to db

Comment: You can simply append the value in string. `value='"+m+"' />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var m = $("#id_manufacturer").val();
$("input[name='phoneManufacturer']").val(m);
```

This way you can assign m value to input having name `phoneManufacturer`

Answer (score 1):

U can Use Jquery Itself

var m = $("#id_manufacturer").val();
var markup = "

**if the name of input is unique then use**

$("phoneManufacturer").val(m);

**else add unique id to input**

$("#someuniqueid").val(m)

$("table tbody").append(markup);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var markup = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td><td><input type="text" name="phoneManufacturer" value="' + m + '"/></td></tr>';
```

**Explanation:** concatenation of `m` in the `value` attribute of `text`

Answer (score 0):

var m = $("#id_manufacturer").val();
$("input[name='phoneManufacturer']").val(m);

Answer (score 0):

To set input box a value ( with Jquery ) like:-

```
<input type="text" value="" id="myInput">

<script>
   var myVal=78; $('#myInput').val(myVal);
</script>
```